# Creating a dropdown list for filtering in Kendo Grid

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

So I need to create a dropdown list for filtering  students name. The names should appear in dropdown list after creating a new record.

```
@using TelerikStudent.Models;
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

@(
Html.Kendo().Grid<Student>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.StudentID).Width(50);
        columns.Bound(p => p.StudentName).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(p => p.StudentSubject).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(p => p.StudentMarks).Width(100);
        columns.Command(command =>
        {
            command.Edit();
            command.Destroy();
        }).Width(100);
    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar=>toolbar.Create())
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .DataSource(dataSource=>dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(10)
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(p => p.StudentID);
            model.Field(p => p.StudentID).Editable(false);
        })
        .Create(create=>create.Action("Create","Students"))
        .Read(read=>read.Action("Read","Students"))
        .Update(update=>update.Action("Update","Students"))
        .Destroy(destroy=>destroy.Action("Destroy","Students"))
    )
)
```

I have tried adding this

```
.ToolBar(toolbar =>
    {
        // dropdown filter name
        toolbar.Template(@<text>
            <label for="NameFilter">Student Name:</label>
            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                .Name("NameFilter")
                .OptionLabel("All")
                .DataTextField("StudentName")
                .DataValueField("StudentName")
                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Read("GetStudentNames", "Students"))
            )
        </text>);
    })
```

controller:

```
public JsonResult GetStudentNames()
    {
        var studentNames = objStudentAccess.GetStudents().Select(p => p.StudentName).Distinct();
        return Json(studentNames);
    }
```

But .Template was showing error

And is this the correct way of doing it